# Stat errors in pthread (S_ISDIR not working)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I am currently attempting to write a program that finds the size of a directory tree as well as the size of all subdirectories within it by creating a thread for each new subdirectory and using that thread to find the size of the subdirectory.  It's a pretty simple program, but it's really hard to debug.  I am having a TON of issues with S_ISDIR not working as intended (regular files are passing the if statement and my program is trying to change dir into regular files).  Below is the code that I have for the problem.  I would like to have each parent directory wait for the subdirectories to finish, but don't want each subdirectory to wait for the next one.

```
#define NAMESIZE 256
#define NUM_THREADS 100
#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 500

int totalSum = 0;
pthread_mutex_t sum_mutex ;
pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex ;

void *findSize(void *p)
{
    int levelSum = 0, numberThreads = 0, i = 0;
    DIR *dir ;
    struct dirent *entry ;
    struct stat entry_stat ;
    char cwd[2049] ;
    char threads[NUM_THREADS] ;
    char paths[NUM_THREADS][MAX_PATH_LENGTH];

    char *path = (char*)p ;

    // change into the directory that was passed in
    if(chdir (p) == -1)
    {
        perror("chdir");
        exit(1);
    }

    // get current working directory
    if(!getcwd (cwd, 2049))
    {
        perror("getcwd") ;
        return;
    }

    // open the directory to get entries within it
    dir = opendir(".") ;
    if(!dir)
    {
        perror("Cannot read directory");
        return;
    }

    while((entry = readdir(dir)))
    {
        // call stat on the current entry in the directory
        if(stat (entry->d_name, &entry_stat) == -1)
        {
            perror("stat error");
        }

        // skip the . and .. directories
        if(strcmp (entry->d_name, ".") == 0)
            continue;
        if(strcmp (entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;

        // check if current entry is a directory
        if(S_ISDIR (entry_stat.st_mode))
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex) ;
            strcpy(paths[numberThreads], cwd) ;
            strcat(paths[numberThreads], "/") ;
            strcat(paths[numberThreads], entry->d_name) ;

            pthread_t temp ;

            // create new thread in threads array
            if (pthread_create(&temp, NULL, findSize, (void *)paths[numberThreads]))
            {
                fprintf("failed to create thread for directory %s\n ", paths[numberThreads]) ;
                exit(1) ;
            }

            threads[numberThreads] = temp;

            // increment the number of threads created on this level of the directory tree

            numberThreads++ ;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex) ;

        }


        if(S_ISREG(entry_stat.st_mode))
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&sum_mutex) ;
            int fileSize = entry_stat.st_size ;
            levelSum += fileSize ;
            totalSum += fileSize ;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&sum_mutex) ;
        }
    }

    void *status ;

    for(i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) ;
    }

}
```

In the main, I simply do pthread_create with my function findSize and the path that the user passes in. I get lots of stat errors, but I can't figure how to fix them..

Comment: I have removed all print statements, but my print statements in my code show attempts to change directory into a file within a subdirectory (which shouldn't be possible because I check S_ISDIR)

Comment: You don't need your own `MAX_PATH_LENGTH`, the system header files already provides `PATH_MAX` for you.

Answer (score 4):

The current directory is not thread-local; it's a property of the process. Thus you're going to end up doing nonsense if each thread tries to `chdir`. You either need to construct full pathnames based on the results from `readdir` without using `chdir`, or use the "*at" interfaces (`openat`, `fstatat`, etc.) to open a file relative to a directory file descriptor.

Comment: okay, I'm trying to rewrite my code without chdir now, I'll update when I get something running.

Comment: I still run into the issue of opendir trying to open regular files.  opendir should only be called on new threads, which are only created for new directories

Comment: Perhaps update your question with a description of the directory tree you're running it on (if that contains private information, try it on a simpler sample tree and see if you can reproduce the problem).